# Zoom in/out in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I want to implement a system to zoom in/zoom out a container div in "real time" with javascript.The container contains different subdivs which are connected through a line using the jsPlumb library My webpage looks something like this:

[image: example]

Is there any 3rd party library which will help me to implement this ? Please advise me where to start. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure but you should see what is in [here](http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment , but the zoom needs to be dynamic , not a predefined value of the zoom...

Answer (score 0):

Looking around the internet, there doesn't appear to be any libraries for what you intend to do- although I would love to be proven wrong.

**Edit:** While working on something completely unrelated to this, I came across a library called [zoom.js](https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js) that allows you zoom in on any element. It's API looks quite easy to use, but it is still a proof of concept, and doesn't work on IE. The creator said specifically to not use it in anything important, which is why I'm keeping my old answer too.

---

However, looking through the source code for [`zoomooz`](https://github.com/jaukia/zoomooz), I'm pretty sure that here's how you do it: Use the [jQuery animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to  slowly apply the change in the [css `transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). More specifically, you want to use the `scale(XValue, YValue)` function for this.

A couple things to remember about using CSS `transform`:

- Set the `transform-origin` property, so that the page fits inside of the screen when scaled, instead of going outside the borders or something similar.
- Include browser specific prefixes like `-webkit-transform`, `-ms-transform`, and `-moz-transform` in addition to `transform`.
- CSS transform is an experimental feature, according to Mozilla, so make sure it is [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) with the browser your users are using.